# Java Nonsynchronized threads using the same resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to make a very simplified Joint Bank Account program (in this example with 3 users who all have access to the bank accounts resources) but I'm having trouble correctly using Java threads.

Here is how the program should work. There are "users" that all have access to one Joint Bank Account with an arbitrary set initial balance(I used 5000). They can each withdraw or deposit money (whether they withdraw or deposit is randomly generated each time) three times over one run of the program.

The amount they deposit or withdraw is also randomly generated, with the only rule for that being that the amount can never exceed 1/3rd of the current balance.

Finaly after each transaction the current Thread has to "wait" a random amount of seconds between 1 and 10.

Now here is the confusing part. Our teacher asked us to make a unique NotEnoughBalance exception class in case one of the users somehow withdraws more money than what is currently in the account (but here is my first point of confusion: in theory this could never occur due to the 1/3rd rule).

Here is the full code posted on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/Upam56NF

Currently, when I run the main:

```
public class BankAccount{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        int capital = 5000;
        JointBankAccount acc = new JointBankAccount(capital);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Owner("Josh", acc));

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Owner("Wade", acc));

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Owner("Ben", acc));

        System.out.println(capital);
        String tname = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(tname);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();      

        for(AccountTransaction s : acc.history){
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(acc.getBalance());
    }

}
```

I randomly sometimes get a NPE exception at System.out.println(s.toString()).

This is completely fixable if I make both deposit and withdraw function Synchronized.

The problem is, somehow I think makign them synchronized defeats the purpose of what our teacher is asking. If I make them synchronized, then I feel like I'm ensuring that the 1/3rd rule gets sucessfuly followed with each withdrawal correctly, and the not enough Balance exception can never exist.

The fact that I get NPEs when I remove synchronized also makes me think possibly the error is in me not properly handling the exception when it does occur. I don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have not `synchronized` anything, then there are no atomicity or visibility guarantees. You almost certainly have a race hazard.

Comment: Sometimes there are things that are never throw. Have anyone ever seen an `InternalError` or an `UnknownError` thrown?

Comment: You mean while running this program? No

Comment: @user1966576 I meant, synchronize properly, add `NotEnoughBalanceException` to your code but never throw it (i.e. throw it when `false == true`).

Comment: If I change the rule so that I stay with 5000 capital at the beginning but the amount withdrawn or deposited can be a random number between 3000 (so no more 1/3rd rule) then the error does correctly occur and get thrown. I just tried it. I think my teacher might have given the assignment wrong. It's like he wants race hazards to occur but it feels like the program makes no sense without making deposit and withdraw synchronzied which make race hazards never occur (with the 1/3rd rule). So idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like a fine exercise in understanding atomic transactions.

But first the NPE: one `JointBankAccount` instance is shared between several threads, and thus anything contained by the `JointBankAccount` like the `history` list. The `history` list is of type `ArrayList` which is not thread-safe, i.e. if two threads call the `add` method at the same time, the list breaks. This is easy to fix though: `List<AccountTransaction> history = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<AccountTransaction>());`

Now for the atomic transactions. Since the balance can be changed at any time by any thread, the moment you read the balance, the balance is already outdated. I.e. a statement like `if (balance > 1000) then updateBalance()` is not valid since the balance could have changed after `then`. One way to circumvent this is to synchronize everything (although even then you have to be careful, e.g. use `AomticInteger` to register the balance). But the `NotEnoughBalanceException` implies a different way of working using a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Before the balance is updated, use a read-lock to read the latest balance and apply any rules to determine if the balance can be updated. This allows you to inform the "owner" that the balance can probably be updated. But since you used a read-lock you cannot be certain: the balance might have already been updated. Now use a write-lock and apply the rules again. This time you can be certain about the balance value (it can only be updated by the code that has the single write-lock) and you might find the balance is no good (one of the rules fails). This is where the `NotEnoughBalanceException` comes into play: you promised the "owner" the balance could be updated but now that you have the final write-lock you find the balance cannot be updated (the atomic transaction cannot be completed).

This follows a pretty common pattern: use "cheap" locks to determine if a transaction can be done (perform pre-checks) and then use an "expensive" lock to perform the transaction but always assume the transaction might fail and retry the transaction when appropriate.